# display values of multiple fields in extjs 4 combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i have a store which has 3 fields:Name,age and phoneNo.
    As of now in my combobox i just display the name ie dispalyField:'Name'.Is there a way,i can display all the 3 fields in the combobox.

I tried using:

```
listConfig : {
  itemTpl : '{Name} {age} {phoneNo}'
}
```

but this shows all the 3 values together like this:

```
John Smith 93831222
John Ford  44222456
```

i want it to be displayed like this in the combobox,one below the other:

```
John 
Smith 
93831222
Ford  
44222456
```

so that i can select any one of these.Any help is highly appreciated...thanks

Comment: Can you add the objects you are trying to render?i.e [{John Smith, 22,93831222},John Ford, 50, 44222456}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
listConfig : {
   getInnerTpl: function(){ return '{Name} - {age}<tpl if="age === null">undefined</tpl> - {phoneno}{email}'; }
}
```

you can add any html code in the template

Comment: good to know this,actaually i have a filter on my store which exactly matches whatever i type and shows only those results.So if i use <br>,will i be able to filter the results.eg if type 12 then it should show me results like 12,1232439 which include both age and phoneNo.Basically,i do not know what the user will type,could be age or phoneNo so i need to show both in the results

Comment: yes you will see always a whole record, if you send this back from the server. maybe you should move the br tag before the age.

Comment: when i use itemTpl,as soon as i try to select any value from the results,the value is not shown in the textfield,it gets wiped off.So shall i be using tpl config?which one could be better?..thanks

Comment: [getInnerTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-method-getInnerTpl) should be right, I updated my post with it.

Comment: For my combobox,I receive the respone in this form:

 data:[{“Name”:”abc”,”age”:12,”phoneno”:27634},
 {“Name”:”rpq”, ”phoneno” :3463432},
 {“Name”:”xyz”,”age”:10,”email”:xyz@xyyz.com}]                        I want the results to be displayes in this format :

abc – 12 -27634
rpq – Undefined -3463432
xyz – 10- xyz@xyyz.com                                              I am using getInnerTpl for this.Basically i need to check first if phoneno/email exist in the response or not and then display phoneno or email...thanks

Comment: I updated my answer for that you can use any javascript expression in the if part